# Abstract Entity and parent relationship in coredata (NSFetchedResultsController + UITableView)

Tags: ios, database-design, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, entities

I am working on a iOS application, the model is very simple (Folders and Documents), but I am having problems for making it working with NSFetchedResultsController.

The app uses a UITableView in a NavigationController for showing a list of folders and documents contained in a folder. The user can browse the folders hierarchy with a drilldown effect. Also, the user can copy/paste folders and documents, so any document or folder could have many parents.

This is my current model:

```
AbstractElement{
    elementName:string
}

Folder{
    parents<<---->>Folder.folders
    folders<<---->>Folder.parents
    documents<<---->>Document.parents
}

Document{
    numPages:int
    parents<<---->>Folder.documents
}
```

This model works fine if I fill the UITableView with an NSArray created from the current folder:

```
NSArray * currentListOfElements = 
      [[self.currentFolder.documents sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors] 
      arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:
      [self.currentFolder.folders sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]];
```

The problem is that I need to fill the UITableView from a NSFetchedResultsController, getting folders and documents with a single NSFetchRequest. The solution is something like that:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"AbstractElement" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.parents", self.currentFolder]];

...create the NSFetchedResultsController using fetchRequest...
```

But this doesn't work because AbstractElement doesn't have "parents" relationship.

If I move parent relationship from Folder and Document to AbstractElement the problem is how to set the inverse relation:

```
AbstractElement{
    elementName:string
    parents<<---->> ??
}

Folder{
    folders<<---->>Folder.parents
    documents<<---->>Document.parents
}

Document{
    numPages:int
}
```

Is this the right aproach? How could I use NSFetchedResultsController with my model? I don't want to remove inverse relations because of the extra code that I need to implement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Louissmr,

You say,

> ... the user can copy/paste folders and documents, so any document or
>   folder could have many parents.

Hence, What is wrong with having 2 to-many relations in the `AbstractElement`. Call them, say, `parents` and `children`. It meets your criteria. Each is the inverse of the other.

Andrew

Comment: Louissmr, And that is a problem? You don't have to actually use the the `children` field for documents. It isn't like this is a lot of storage to let lay fallow. If you want, you can even override the accessors to preclude setting anything to the `children`. Having the relationships in the `AbstractEntity` is a good solution to the problem you specified. It is simple and easy to use. Andrew

Comment: Thanks Andrew. If I use the children relation I will lose folders and documents relationships. I am using these relationships for knowing how many folders and documents there are in a folder. int numFolders = currentFolder.folders.count; int numDocs = currentFolder.documents.count; Probably I will use your solution, but I am trying to find a better one.